# perspective plot in R (tick marks and understanding what is going on)

Tags: r, graphics, plot, lattice

I plot a 3d plot in R using `persp`. I have two questions with respect to this:

1. Want to verify that I understand the docs correctly. `persp` will take the valuex from `x` and `y`, then depending on the *index* of each value in those vectors, say `(i,j)` corresponding to the current element in `x` and `y`, `(x[i],y[j])`, it will pluck out `zfit[i,j]` and plot `(x[i],y[j],zfit[i,j])`. Is this correct?
2. This does not produce the numbers on the actual axis but arrows in the increasing direction. How do I make numbers appear?

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
z = x + y^2
g = expand.grid(list(x=seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length.out=100),y=seq(from=min(y), to=max(y), length.out=100)))
mdl = loess(z ~ x+ y)
zfit = predict(mdl, newdata=g)
persp(x = seq(from=min(x), to=max(x), length.out=100), y = seq(from=min(y), to=max(y), length.out=100), z= zfit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 - Your understanding is correct.

## 2 - Add ticktype = "detailed" to show numbers on axis.